# How to create div with content?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, semantic-ui

I have select menu using semantic UI. When I click the menu, I need to add div with content and class of the selected menu is being created.

```
<div class="required field">
    <h4 class="ui dividing header">Soluation Body</h4>
    <div class="ui dropdown ui selection dropdown" style="max-width: 300px; margin-right: 17px;">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Soluation Body</div>
        <dev class="menu" >
            <div class="item" value="file">File Upload <span style="color: gray;">( zip )</span></div>
            <div class="item" value="repository">Repository <span style="color: gray;">( github , gitlap ,...)</span></div>
            <div class="item" value="list">List <span style="color: gray;">( futuers , basics )</span></div>
            <div class="item" value="code">Code Editor <span style="color: gray;">( Code )</span></div>
            <div class="item" value="image">Image <span style="color: gray;">( analysis || flow chart )</span></div>
        </dev>
    </div>
    <div class="ui button">Add</div>

</div>
```

So if I choose the element with value="file"

```
 <div class="required field">
     <input type="file" name="file-upload">
 </div>
```

and if clicked again and the same file is selected

```
 <div class="required field">
     <input type="file" name="file-upload-2">
 </div>
```

So is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand what you want - but you can toggle on events with v-if

Comment: @Estradiaz  i need my select here to generate dev with different classes and content foreach value in select

Comment: @Kareem you misunderstand vue. Vue is declarative/functional reactive. You declare everything you want in the template then choose which to show. E.g. Using v-if or otherwise. This is not JQuery where you add things when an event triggers. (or https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-switch-case)